# Convert multiple sub-queries to on join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple sub-queries in my sql

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT Col1 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE SAME) AS Col1,
(SELECT Col2 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE SAME) AS Col2,
(SELECT Col3 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE SAME) AS Col3,
(SELECT Col4 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE SAME) AS Col4,
FROM MYTABLE1 WHERE XXX
```

How can I convert this to in one JOIN? Sub Query is same only the Select column-name is different.

Comment: How are the two tables related? What does the where clauses do? Is it the same conditions in the subqs as the outer q?

Comment: Can you expand `SAME` to the actual code used in your query?

Comment: sub query is same only select column is different. @MarkBannister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MYTABLE1.*, MYTABLE2.*
  FROM MYTABLE1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MYTABLE2  
    ON same 
 WHERE XXX
```

The ON does not have to relate the two tables
This is more like a filtered cross join

Comment: Either.  Depends on what you want.  If same returns no rows and you want the MYTABLE1 then outer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use UNION and not JOIN?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have enough reputation to comment :/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4
FROM MYTABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN MYTABLE2 T2 
ON T1.somecol = T2.somecol --replace with appropriate join condition
WHERE XXX 
and --same conditions as previous (WHERE SAME)
```

This is what you would do. You should make the needed changes as per the comments in-line.

Comment: what if T2 not matched

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: what if T1.somecol <> T2.somecol

Comment: @user960567 - If you know that the conditions in the WHERE clause only ever yield ***exactly one*** record, you can use `CROSS JOIN`.  Take care though, it sounds like you have a design problem *(joining tables without explicit relationships in a relational database is a code-smell, and CROSS JOIN can make problems explode.)*

Comment: your tables would be joined on that condition.You should see how the results would change by altering the conditions.

Comment: If table1 is not somehow related the table2 then what would be the purpose of the query?  Why do you ask how to join if you don't have something to join on?